# Hibernate subquery detachedCriteria

Tags: hibernate, subquery, detachedcriteria

How to write a subquery in hibernate which is having multiple subqueries. for example

```
select * from project_dtls where project_id in  
  (select project_id from project_users where user_id =
  (select user_id from user_dtls where email='abc@email.com'))
```

I know that we can write through DetachedCriteria but couldnot find any example where I can use multiple subqueries.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example:

```
DetachedCriteria exampleSubquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyPersistedObject.class)
    .setProjection(Property.forName("id"))
    // plus any other criteria...
    ;

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(ARelatedPersistedObject.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("myPersistedObjectId", exampleSubquery)));
```

For multiple subqueries, you can use a boolean operator like Restrictions.or():

```
DetachedCriteria anotherSubquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyPersistedObject.class)
    .setProjection(Property.forName("id"))
    // plus any other criteria...
    ;

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(ARelatedPersistedObject.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .add(Restrictions.or(
        Subqueries.propertyIn("myPersistedObjectId", exampleSubquery),
        Subqueries.propertyIn("myPersistedObjectId", anotherSubquery)));
```

Comment: Sounds like it didn't work.  If you can provide some more details, perhaps the code you tried, maybe we can help more.

Comment: Well, your example doesn't actually replicate his code. He has a subquery inside a subquery but yours is just an OR.

Comment: This question asks how to do it with DetachedCriteria.  Your answer shows how to do it with Criteria.  This is different and doesn't exactly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

To do it entirely with Detached Criteria (because I like to construct the detached criteria without a session)

```
DetachedCriteria idQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyPersistedObject.class)
    .setProjection(Property.forName("id"))
DetachedCriteria recordQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyPersistedObject.class)
    .add(Property.forName("id").eq(idQuery) );
```